# Vuex API call if page need it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, vuex, vue-router

i have a VueJS project and i need to load data when page need it. Like, profile page needs user's informations, appointments page needs user's appointments data etc.

**My solution so far:**

I am checking data in every component's beforeRouteEnter function. If data null then i load the data from vuex action. This is the worst solution for this problem because code always repeating itself.

Profile.Vue:

```
beforeRouteEnter: async (to, from, next) => {
    if(!store.state.provinces)
        await store.dispatch("getProvinces")
    next()
},
```

Appointments.vue

```
beforeRouteEnter: async (to, from, next) => {
    if(!store.state.provinces)
        await store.dispatch("getProvinces")
    next()
},
```

**My second strategy:**
I thought if i use getters instead of states maybe it will be work but when i use getters, now data loads after route.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use created method in your related vue component. You can check this link for more detail: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Comment: Yes, i did that but created method is not a async function. It's rendering the page even while data fetching. You didn't understand my problem. I don't want to check and fetch every state variable in every component.If data is null, then fetch the data from server.

Comment: you can call your dispatch method in your created section. did u try that ?

Comment: Yes but i don't want to call the dispatch in every component. If data is loaded i don't have to load the data again right? I am checking data if it's null or not and fetch from my server. I don't want to write again and again...

Comment: there is also another solution for that. mixins. Where is yoru data coming from ? What do you mean if data is loaded. Can you explain yourself better ?

Comment: I load data from my API. It's clear right? I am checking data in Vuex and if data is null then i get data from my API server. It's crystal clear right now. So i don't want to check data if null in every component.  Do you understand what i mean?

Comment: no i dont understand what you mean. What is API server and what is the difference between your API and your API server ? You have to call your function to get your data so you can also check if your data is null or not in the related vue component.